# reactive programming store result in a variable

Tags: python, reactive-programming, rx-py

quick (trivial) question: I cannot find a way to store the output of a series of operation on an observable in an external variable. 
For instance something like that:

```
mylist = []
Observable.from_([1, 2, 3]).to_list().store(mylist)
```

Not sure this is very "reactive", but should be trivial.

Thanks in advance

C

Comment: What have you actually tried, and what went wrong with it/them?

Comment: For example: mylist = []
Observable.from_([1, 2, 3]).to_list().subscribe(lambda l: mylist=l). But it is not a valid python code.

Comment: I could write my own Observer to store the data (the list) in some variable, but I am wondering if such functionality exists already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn your observable into a blocking one via `.to_blocking()`. Now you can iterate over it.

```
mylist=list(Observable.from_([1, 2, 3]).to_blocking())                                                                   

print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution i found:

```
mylist = []

def store(value):
    mylist.append(value)

Observable.from_([1, 2, 3]).do_action(store).subscribe()

print(mylist)
```

Comments?

Thanks